# Understanding how MagicHaskeller generates functions

Tags: haskell

I stumbled upon this product : http://nautilus.cs.miyazaki-u.ac.jp/~skata/MagicHaskeller.html and am very impressed that it can generate a function by providing a specification.

Reading a paper about MagicHaskeller : https://www.haskell.org/haskell-symposium/2013/magichaskeller.pdf provides a clue to how this works :

```
The backend server does the actual program synthesis. The synthesis
algorithm takes a generate-and-test approach: it generates an
infinite stream of all the expressions having the same type as f;
then, they are tested against the given predicate. The implementation
is based on [2] which discusses how to efficiently generate a
stream of expressions with the given type using memoization, and
[3] which discusses how to remove semantically equivalent expressions.
There are also new devices to reduce heap usage further.
```

I'm currently learning Haskell and I think learning to implment a basic similar MagicHaskeller would be a very interesting way to learn the language.

Is there a particular concept behind MagicHaskeller that I can utilize to perform something similar ?

Comment: From the paper you linked (section 3): "The synthesis algorithm takes a generate-and-test approach: it generates an infinite stream of all the expressions having the same type as f ; then, they are tested against the given predicate."

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you are learning Haskell, perhaps starting with reproducing a research-level task from 2013 is a bit too much. I would start with some tutorial and some basic exercises, first.

Comment: I disagree. You may also be interested in https://github.com/lspitzner/exference/